# my JavaScript print code work but not getting with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

code is hear

```
var d=new Date();
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = '<HTML>\n<head>\n<title>CLS -' + d.getTime() +'</title>\n<link href="<?php echo JURI::base();?>templates/cls/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />\n</head>\n<body>' + document.getElementById('result_content').innerHTML + "</body>\n</HTML>" ;
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
    setTimeout('window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()',300);
```

this code is work fine but when it is print then not print with css style...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not have a print style sheet e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Comment: not in the js where your add the html to the frame you are trying to print

Comment: thats probably something else

Answer (score 0):

Mine also print not working with css.
below is my code:

```
window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = '<HTML>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<link href="style.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n</head>\n<body>' + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML + "</body>\n</HTML>";
window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
```